# Python: proper way to implement `l[s:e] += v`

Tags: python, range, operator-overloading

I'm implementing for fun and profit a data-structure allowing fast additive range updates:

```
class RAUQ:
    """  Allow 'l[s:e] += v' update and 'a[i]' query in O(log n)

    >>> l = RAUQ([0, 10, 20]) ; l
    [0, 10, 20]
    >>> l[1]
    10
    >>> l[2] += 10 ; l
    [0, 10, 30]
    >>> l[0:2] += 3 ; l
    [3, 13, 30]
    >>> l[1:10] -= 4 ; l # Support usual out of bounds slices
    [3, 9, 26]
    """
```

According to disassembled bytecode, the `l[i] += v` expression is translated to:

```
l.__setitem__(i, l.__getitem__(i).__iadd__(v))
```

which I find pretty weird (inplace add, and set anyway?).

So, S.O., what would be a nice and pythonic way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. Does the job, but feels hackish.

```
class RAUQ:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        # Stripped down example,
        # actual implementation use segment tree.
        self.l = list(iterable)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return _view(self, i)
        return self.l[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            """ No-op: work already done in view"""
            return self
        self.l[i] = val
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(_view(self, slice(None)))

    __repr__ = __str__


class _view:

    def __init__(self, parent, i):
        # generic implementation non designed for single index.
        assert isinstance(i, slice)
        self.l = parent.l
        self.i = i

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.l[self.i])

    def update(self, val):
        """ Add val to all element of the view """
        self.l[self.i] = [x+val for x in self]

    def __iadd__(self, val):
        self.update(val)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, val):
        self.update(-val)
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(self))

    __repr__ = __str__
```

Comment: Hackish or not, this is the only way; augmented assignment to a slice first has to load the slice, then apply `__iadd__` to the result.

Comment: This doesn't properly support slice assignments; you've implemented them in a way that only works if `__getitem__` has previously been called with the same slice. If you try `r = RAUQ([1]); r[:1] = [5]; print(r[0])` you'll get 1 as output instead of the expected 5.

Comment: If I found myself in a situation where I needed to do stuff like this, chances are I'd be working with numpy where broadcasting makes this possible by default.

Comment: @rawing: You're right. I've only implemented the part I needed (RHS is a scalar, not an arbitrary iterable).

Comment: @Martijn: I would have expected either `l.__getitem__(i).__iadd__(v)` (à la C++: the getter returns a view/reference) or a version with `__add__` (expressing `l[i] = l[i] + v`)

Comment: @YvesgereY: you get exactly what you expected, but `__iadd__()`'s result is always assigned back. So it's `l.__getitem__(sliceobj).__iadd__(v)` with the return value assigned back with `l.__setitem__(sliceobj, result)`.